# How to redirect webpage from one domain to another?

Tags: javascript, html, http, asp-classic

How to redirect domain to another domain, when the first domain (webpage) load?

Answer (score 18):

A pure HTML alternative is the following `<meta>` tag in your HTML `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;http://anotherdomain.com">
```

The `0` is here the amount of seconds the page has to stay open before redirecting. In this case, it'll happen immediately as soon as you loads the page. In contrary to the proposed JS solution, this will work fine as well in browsers with JS disabled.

However, if you've the ability to hook on server side code without trouble (i.e. response is not committed yet and so on), then I'd prefer that above the HTML/JS solution anyway.

Comment: Sadly this just appends the uri to the end of the current path, not redirecting to that site.

Comment: Just use an absolute URL instead of a relative URL?

Answer (score 15):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  One is to add the an onload event to the body tag what sets window.location to the new domain.

```
<script language=javascript>
function redirect(){
  window.location = "http://example.com";
}
</script>

<body onload="redirect()">

</body>
```

Comment: A lot more efficient to use the ASP.NET redirect header approach, but this will certainly work. (As long as JavaScript is enabled.)

Comment: Agreed.  Depending on the server setup, there could be a redirect on the web server level as well.  BalusC has a good solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% Response.Redirect ("http://example.com") %>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309(VS.90).aspx) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to do it the HTML way (meta refresh), e.g. if you want to add a conditional check, then you can use JavaScript as the last resort to redirect to a different domain by setting the hostname (not host) part of the URL like this:

```
<script>
     window.location.hostname = 'new-domain-example.com'
</script>
```

This will redirect you to the same URL (including protocol, port, query string, hash) but with the domain replaced.
Note that this script can be placed in the HTML head with the meta tags (https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/301-redirects#jslocation).

Here is a nice visualization to understand all properties on the location object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#location_anatomy