# Javascript redirect to same folder on different domain?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm trying to redirect users from one site to another but keep the part after the domain name the same. For example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/this-is-a-blog-post.html
```

to

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/this-is-a-blog-post.html
```

Can this be done using a javascript redirect? If so, what would the code look like? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect webpage from one domain to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450351/how-to-redirect-webpage-from-one-domain-to-another)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the `window.location` object. If you just want to change the domain (keeping the same path) use this code.

`window.location = "http://newwebsite.com/" + window.location.pathname;`

If you want to do anything more sophisticated, you can mess with the `window.location.pathname` value and use that to redirect.

Answer (score 3):

To change just the domain and leave everything else (including protocol, port, query string, hash, etc), I'd use...

```
window.location.hostname = 'example.com';
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSBps/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to see your dns configuration to do that properly. Your Cname A record can be used to create aliases. Is it worth this hack, long term you would be better of saying we have moved ...

Answer (score 0):

Append `window.location.search` also if you need query parameters in the url as well.

```css
open() {
    var win = window.open('https://newebsite.com/' + window.location.pathname + window.location.search, '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="open()">Open</button>
```